# I have a problem with a leaked window that was originally added here after the hide in onDoInBackground show file update

Tags: java, android, memory-leaks

error code in page splashcreen activity in after call download uri manual in app.

```
E/WindowManager: android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.telkom.indihome.partner.SplashActivity has leaked window DecorView@463b913[SplashActivity] that was originally added here
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:589)
    at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:360)
    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:105)
    at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:404)
    at com.telkom.indihome.partner.SplashActivity$DownloadTask.onPreExecute(SplashActivity.java:355)
    at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:620)
    at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:567)
    at com.telkom.indihome.partner.SplashActivity$CheckVersionAsc$1.onClick(SplashActivity.java:187)
    at android.support.v7.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:166)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6823)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1563)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1451)
```

Comment: It seems like you are showing some kind of dialog maybe progress dialog or alert dialog in onPreExecute and not dismissing it onPostExecute. Can you post your code here.

Comment: Can you Solve issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Some points helpful in the comments**

1. You make sure Dialog show after exiting the `Activity` and Dialog Instance.
2. Call `dismiss()`of the Dialog instance created before exiting  `Activity` ex: `onPause()` , `onDestroy()`
3. For Example : `@Override public void onStop() { if (dialog != null) { dialog.dismiss(); dialog = null; }}`